# What is the point of the [data-science] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have a [data-science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-science) tag? It's quite obviously redundant, and it could be applied to every question on the site, so why does it exist? This seems like having a [programming] tag on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), or a [cooking] tag on [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, that tag is worthless - I've removed and blacklisted it.

[datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datascience) was already blocked by default.

Answer (score 3):

The tag is obviously redundant. But this is typical for all SE sites.

Comment: Can you give examples? I can't find `programming` or `coding` tag on stackoverflow